# Azure k8s HPA on custom metric

Tags: azure, prometheus, azure-aks, hpa

I am trying to achieve HPA on azure cluster. But it is not working as expected, as it is not scaling up the pods when it is clearly showing the metric value is double of the target value. As you can see in the below screenshot

[image]

[image]

Here is the HPA configuration for the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might be your Metrics server is not automatically installed with AKS,The Metrics Server is used to provide resource utilization to Kubernetes, and is automatically deployed in AKS clusters versions 1.10 and higher.
To see the version of your AKS cluster, use the `az aks show` command, as shown in the following example:

```
az aks show --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --query kubernetesVersion --output table
```

If your AKS cluster is less than 1.10, the Metrics Server is not automatically installed. You can install via url.

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.3.6/components.yaml
```

To use the autoscaler, all containers in your pods and your pods must have CPU requests and limits defined.

For more information how to implement you can refer this [**Microsoft Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-scale?tabs=azure-cli#autoscale-pods)